# How to connect CakePHP to a Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

I'm just starting with CakePHP, I went through the blog tutorial without trouble but would now like to try it with a proper DBMS like postgres. I tweaked the database.php file to point to a database I created in my local postgres instance:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '5432',
        'login' => 'cakephp',
        'password' => 'cakephp',
        'database' => 'cakephp',
        'schema' => 'blog_tuto',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );

    public $test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '5432',
        'login' => 'cakephp',
        'password' => 'cakephp',
        'database' => 'cakephp',
        'schema' => 'blog_tuto',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

I have no issues connecting to this database with a SQL client, but CakePHP complains with the following message:

```
CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.

Database connection "Postgres" is missing, or could not be created.
Selected driver is not enabled
```

I already verified that the postgres DboSource class in present. The postgres php module is also installed:

```
$ php -m | grep pg
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

**Update I** : The output of phpinfo related to Postgres goes below:

```
pdo_pgsql
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL   enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.1.9
Module version  1.0.2
Revision    $Id: pdo_pgsql.c 321634 2012-01-01 13:15:04Z felipe $

pgsql
PostgreSQL Support  enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.1.9
Multibyte character support     enabled
SSL support     enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pgsql.allow_persistent  On  On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent Off Off
pgsql.ignore_notice Off Off
pgsql.log_notice    Off Off
pgsql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
pgsql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
```

**Update II** : When I accessed the application today trying to follow [Ajir's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948599/how-to-connect-cakephp-to-a-postgres-database#comment42869042_27106796) I surprisingly got a different error message: "Authentication failed" - meaning that CakePHP is now able to connect. I installed Postgres 9.3 some months ago and had not re-created the tutorial objects; all I needed to do was run the SQL script and the tutorial application is now fully functional.

Whatever is wrong is likely restricted to Postgres 9.1.

Comment: Please check that the PostGres module has been loaded/activated in your web server.
Or run phpinfo(); and check that you can see Postgres module has been loaded and is available.
Kindly inform us of the result.

Comment: `I already verified that the postgres DboSource class in present` You've done that on the cli, but the error message is from the webserver - they won't be using the same php.ini file.

Comment: AD7six, what client are you speaking of? As far I know all my code runs server side.

Comment: I am having the same problem, I am using the built-in Apache/PHP in Mac OS X Mavericks, I am also using Codeigniter in this same server, Codeigniter is able to connect to postgres without problem, I also made a postgres test script that is also being able to connect to postgres, I double checked my cakePHP database.php config file, what could I check for ? thanks --- public $default = array( 'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres', 'persistent' => false, 'host' => 'localhost', 'login' => 'cake', 'password' => 'cake', 'database' => 'cake', 'schema' => 'cake');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely an issue related to Postgres to 9.1, Cake PHP works perfectly fine with Postgres 9.3. Not a real solution, but a work around to fix this problem is:

1. Backup the database(s) hosted by Postgres 9.1.
2. Install Postgres 9.3 (eventually running in an alternative port).
3. Restore the database(s) into Postgres 9.3.
4. Point the `database.php` configuration to Postgres 9.3 (if it is running in an alternative port).
5. Remove Postgres 9.1 (if not needed).

Answer (score 1):

This could resolve your problem :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Comment: have you tried to check the CakePHP/Apache/Postgres logs ?

Answer (score 0):

my configuration : Windows 7, IIS 7.5, php 5.3, postrgres 9.4, cakephp 2.6.3

i've just added:

`extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`

at the end of php.ini file after all extensions(php.ini copy of development).
Remember that files must be presented C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext (this is my path to php installation)

Answer (score -1):

please be sure that the schema that you are using is `blog_tuto` and not `public` which is the default in Postgresql. To test it, try to switch `blog_tuto` with `public`.

And to avoid encoding problems, I'd suggest you to remove the comment of the encoding line and put there the encoding that you are using in your database (e.g. UTF-8, LATIN1);